# Distance to source populations and/or environmental gradients?

Tags: community-ecology, landscape-ecology

How do you disentangle the effects of distance to source populations and environmental gradients when the environmental gradient occurs in the same direction as the source population?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iWDfblq.png]

For example, if I have a regression model with species richness as the independent variable and distance to source population and pH as significant dependent variables, how do I know which is the driving factor?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Where does the figure come from? The article who made this figure might help you to answer your question. What have you found so far?

Comment: The effects of distance to source populations and environmental gradients on WHAT? Species Richness? Pairwise $F_{ST}$?

Comment: pH? Are you referring to scale to measure acidity and basicity? Is this just one example of possible environmental variable that you are giving?

Comment: I made the figure in powerpoint to ask the question. lol

Comment: This question would be just as suitable (if not more) at [SE-CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, species richness is most likely the *dependent* variable (the one you want to explain), while distance to the source pool and pH are the *independent* variables (the ones you assume to have an effect on species richness).

The problem you are describing is termed [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) and a common problem in regression analyses. The good news is that it does not affect the prediction of your model as a whole. The bad news is that the estimates for you individual predictors become increasingly erratic the higher their correlation is. You can estimate the severeness of multicollinearity in your model with the Variance inflation factor (VIF). Wikipedia explains nicely how to interpret the VIF:

> The square root of the variance inflation factor tells you how much larger the standard error is, compared with what it would be if that variable were uncorrelated with the other predictor variables in the model.
>
> Example
> If the variance inflation factor of a predictor variable were 5.27 (√5.27 = 2.3) this means that the standard error for the coefficient of that predictor variable is 2.3 times as large as it would be if that predictor variable were uncorrelated with the other predictor variables.

You should calculate the VIF for your model. Many sources state that a VIF < 10 is still acceptable, but since [there is no rule of thumb](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-006-9018-6), I suggest to do some further reading on the topic if you get some critical value (just google "dealing with collinearity" and you'll find tons of material).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My VIFs for all the variables are less than 2.  So thats good. Regression between my distance to source and pH returns a r2 of .2. And the distance contributes ~.18 to the variance of richness. I'm just worried that explanatory power of distance is actually just pH. meh. EDIT: richness is dependent, space and environment are independent. ha.

Comment: Could some type of null model work here?

Comment: To partition the R² you can start out with a single-predictor model and add predictors while keeping track of the increment in R². However, since your predictors are not completely uncorrelated, the partial R² will differ depending on the order of variable entrance. Another way to compare effect sizes would be to standardize each variable (i.e. compute z-values) and look at the estimated coefficients.